# Does “skid” have a meaning as “losing games (successively)”？

Tags: word-meaning

> Auburn ends 2-game skid with 26-10 win over No. 25 A&M.

I looked into my dictionaries (Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary,Londman Advanced American Dictionary, and Collins Cobuild Advanced Dictionary),but didn't find a suitable meaning for that "2-game skid". I guess it means the team stopped its repeated defeats, doesn't it?

Does “skid” have a specific meaning used in the domain of sports as “losing games (successively)”？

Is it acceptable to say "one-game skid"?

Why is this meaning or such an example not specifically included in famous dictionaries such as Oxford and Longman?

Comment: You should check more than one dictionary. Here are 30 to 40 dictionaries with'skid', all at one website. [One Look Dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=skid&ls=a). The second dictionary there (American Heritage) has your answer. And no, we would not say a one-game skid, because a skid is 'repeated losses'. I find even a 'two-game skid' to be a bit iffy, but I guess some writers don't expect their teams to lose more than one in a row.

Comment: @User1  I've checked Oxford Advanced Learner Dictionary, Longman Advanced American Dictionary, and there's not a very appropriate meaning for "2-game skid". (Maybe you should put blame on my poor  language associative ability as a non-native.) I don't have American Heritage Dictionary at hand. It seems such usage is quite common in English, then I wonder if it's a defect not to include  the meaning "repeated losses" for "skid" in famous dictionaries like Oxford and Longman.

Comment: I, an English learner, don't think my post an off-topic one. Nevertheless, I accept the rules here.

Comment: Okay, I think it should be reopened because Oxford and Collins doesn't have a helpful definition. But now you have the link for One Look in my other comment. (Do you know how many questions we get from people who just want a definition? We try to send people to dictionaries because thar js a tool language learners need to know how to use.)

Comment: [this version](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/skid_2) of Longman has the exact definition you need, and an example (*six-game skid*). As for *one-game skid*, a skid is a period of time, or a number of games in a row. It would be rare to say *one-game skid*, and it would probably be used in an ironic way.

Comment: @User1 Thank you for your understanding and help:) I do like One Look Dictionary you gave me!

Comment: @dennylv: For clarity, "off-topic" doesn't really mean off topic in this case. It just means that there's a particular reason defined here on ELL for closing questions that doesn't exist elsewhere on the network.

Answer (score 1):

**Skid row** was the term used for impoverished areas, a place where homeless drunks would wind up living, for example the Bowery back in the day. **On the skids** is slang for having a difficult time.  One can easily see the extension into your example.

Comment: Seattle's "[Skid Road](https://books.google.com/books?id=viEhAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA210)" was a steeply sloping road from hills (covered with tall trees) down to a sawmill on the harbor. At the bottom of the road was a notorious red-light district, complete with bars and brothels. Thus, the term represented both (for a log) a literal long-and-steep drop toward its fate and (for a person) a figurative long-and-steep drop in social status.